# SQL Server - Query to exclude values only when record has a null date

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this. I'm using SQL Server Azure. I'm trying to return all the COLORs that are not RED and don't have a `Date_Painted` value - Date is null

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COLORS]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [COLOR] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
    [DATE_PAINTED] [SMALLDATETIME] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_COLORS] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[COLORS] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[COLORS] ([ID], [COLOR], [DATE_PAINTED]) 
VALUES (1, N'RED', CAST(N'2000-01-01T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime)),
       (2, N'BLUE', CAST(N'2000-01-01T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime)),
       (3, N'GREEN', NULL),
       (4, N'PURPLE', CAST(N'2000-01-01T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime)),
       (5, N'BLACK', NULL),
       (6, N'WHITE', CAST(N'2000-01-01T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime)),
       (7, N'ORANGE', CAST(N'2000-01-01T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime)),
       (8, N'YELLOW', CAST(N'2000-01-01T00:00:00' AS SmallDateTime)),
       (9, N'RED', NULL)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[COLORS] OFF
```

The query should return all records except `RED` and `DATE_PAINTED NULL`

Obviously this does not work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM COLORS
WHERE COLOR <> 'RED' AND DATE_PAINTED IS NOT NULL
```

What is the correct/best query. Also table has over 25,000 records.

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: What do you mean that query doesnt work obviously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM COLORS
WHERE NOT (COLOR = 'RED' AND DATE_PAINTED IS NULL);
```

The equivalent logic (assuming `COLOR` is never `NULL`) without `NOT` is:

```
SELECT *
FROM COLORS
WHERE COLOR <> 'RED' OR DATE_PAINTED IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[COLORS]
WHERE COLOR <> 'RED' OR DATE_PAINTED IS NOT NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b8899/5

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you want everything EXCEPT row with ID of 1 or everything except row 9 or something I didn't interpret from your question.

Everything but row with ID 1 - where color red AND date_painted is not null

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.COLORS
WHERE (COLOR<>'RED') OR (DATE_PAINTED IS NULL);
```

Everything but row 9 where color is red and date painted is null - which does the same thing that @Gordon Linoff suggested.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.COLORS
WHERE (COLOR<>'RED') OR (DATE_PAINTED IS NOT NULL);
```